# Only plotting the fitted spline line and not the data points

Tags: r, spline

I have checked my references, it seems to me that to fit a dataset with x and y, many tutorial need to first plot the x and y,  then the fitted line is plot. The normal procedure is like below:

```
## Calculate the fitted line
smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(tree_number[2:100], jaccard[1:99], spar=0.35) 
plot(tree_number[2:100],jaccard[1:99]) #plot the data points
lines(smoothingSpline) # add the fitted spline line.
```

However, I do not want to plot the tree_number and jaccard, but rather, I only want to plot the fitted spline line in the plot, how should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the associcated plot function:

```
plot(smoothingSpline, type="l")
```

Or you can extract the `x` and `y` values explicitly and plot them

```
plot(smoothingSpline$x, smoothingSpline$y, type="l")
```

Comment: thanks!!, how do I add a horizontal line like(y=0.8) to this plot

Answer (score 4):

Why not just `plot(smoothingSpline, type = "l")`? That should allow you to add the fitted spline line without having to first plot the data points.